# Can't seem to send email with jhipster application

Tags: spring, email, jhipster

I'm trying to make a simple form that when submited sends and email to a fixed email.

I'm using spring and i've searched on how to configure the application.yml and i'm using the mailsend method that seems to have been generated with my jhipster application.

I've built my FE service to connect to the back end :

```
 sendForm(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(SERVER_API_URL + 'api/sendForm', "");
  }
```

i've built the onsubmit method to make the subscribe to the method above:

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.auth.sendForm().subscribe( data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

i've hard coded the mail resource just to mock an email to make sure its working:

```
    @PostMapping("/sendForm")
    public void sendForm() {
        this.mailService.sendEmail("mymail@gmail.com","Header","texto",false,true);
    }
```

the sendMail method that im sending the information for the mail submition is autogenerated and I believe it should be working

```
 @Async
    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String content, boolean isMultipart, boolean isHtml) {
        log.debug("Send email[multipart '{}' and html '{}'] to '{}' with subject '{}' and content={}",
            isMultipart, isHtml, to, subject, content);

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setFrom(jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom());
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(content, isHtml);
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
            log.debug("Sent email to User '{}'", to);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}'", to, e);
            } else {
                log.warn("Email could not be sent to user '{}': {}", to, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

and heres my application-dev.yml (i'm still on dev)

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
    mail:
        host: smtp.gmail.com
        port: 587
        username: gmailuserid@gmail.com  #Replace this field with your Gmail username.
        password: ************           #Replace this field with your Gmail password.
        protocol: smtp
        tls: true
        properties.mail.smtp:
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
            ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

the errors im getting goes as follows:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localh
ost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Failed messages: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeo
ut -1;
```

All I expect is a mail with the mock i've used and I cant seem to be able to put this working.

I hope i've not made the post to long and that everything is well explained.

Thank you in advance for anyone willing to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently somewhy the properties-prod.yml wasnt being loaded to the server. I had to create a config file with all the configurations for it to work